# c++ initializing array storage size

Tags: c++, arrays

```
void start ( string fname )
{   
    string FirstElement;    
    int count = 0 ;
    fstream Infile;
    Infile.open( fname.c_str(), ios::in ); // Open the input file 

    while(!Infile.eof()) // using while to look for the total lines
    {
        count++;
    }

    //read to the array
    string data_array[]; //initializing an array
    for(int i=0; !Infile.eof(); i++){
        Infile >> data_array[i]; // storing the value read from file to array

    }

    //Display the array
//    for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
    //    cout << data_array[i] << endl;

    //}
    cout << data_array[0] << endl;
    cout << count << endl;
    return;

}
```

I have a text files contain values lines by lines
My plan was to use the while loop to do a total count of the lines
and place it in the "string data_array[]" but somehow it doesnt work that way.
anyone can advise me on how can I make it in a way that It can have a flexible storage size going according to the numbers of values in the text files? thanks

Comment: you can use `vector<string> `

Comment: `eof()` returning `false` does not mean the next read will succeed. Check that the last read succeeded before assuming it did.

Comment: Your use of `eof()` is wrong in both places. Just don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

For *flexible storage* as you call it, you may use STL's container, such as [`std::vector<T>`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector) or [`std::list<T>`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/list/list). Other issues are highlighted in inline comments.

```
// pass by reference
void start(const std::string& fname)
{       
    // use std::ifstream, instead of std::fstream(..., std::ios::in);
    std::ifstream Infile(fname.c_str()); 

    // prefer std::vector to raw array
    std::vector<std::string> data_array; 
    std::string line;

    // read line by line
    while (std::getline(Infile, line)) 
    {
        data_array.push_back(line); // store each line
    }

    // print out size
    std::cout << data_array.size() << std::endl;

    // display the array, note: indexing starts from 0 not 1 !
    for(int i = 0; i < data_array.size(); ++i)
    {
       std::cout << data_array[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```